Keyboard decimal separator
Sometimes it’s necessary to determine the decimal separator, especially if you’re working with a keyboard that uses a decimal separator (TextInputType.numberWithOptions(decimal: true)).
It’s often recommended to find the separator using the intl package, but this won’t work, as shown in the Language & Region settings, where the Number format is independent of Preferred Languages.


You can make it by adding a method in a plugin.
AppDelegate.swift

import UIKit
import Flutter

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
    let controller : FlutterViewController = window?.rootViewController as! FlutterViewController
    let decimalChannel = FlutterMethodChannel(name: "com.example.app/channel",
                                              binaryMessenger: controller.binaryMessenger)
    
    decimalChannel.setMethodCallHandler { (call: FlutterMethodCall, result: @escaping FlutterResult) -> Void in
      if call.method == "getDecimalSeparator" {
        let decimalSeparator = Locale.current.decimalSeparator ?? "."
        result(decimalSeparator)
      } else {
        result(FlutterMethodNotImplemented)
      }
    }

    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}


flutter code:
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

Future<String> getSeparator() async {
  if (Platform.isIOS) {
    final utils = MethodChannel('com.example.app/channel');

      final String decimalSeparator = await channel.invokeMethod('getDecimalSeparator');
  } else {
    final format = NumberFormat.decimalPattern(Platform.localeName);

    return format.symbols.DECIMAL_SEP;
  }
}



Or rather than NumberFormatter, perhaps Locale.current.decimalSeparator.

Updated. thanks @Rob.
